# Accessing Local file from Web Site in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

I have a simple Web Application created in Visual Studio.  I simply want to access an XML file that I have added to the package.

This is the hierarchy

```
Root---index.aspx
  ¦----myxml.xml
```

but whenever i reference myxml.xml in the c# code for my index page, I get a file not found error?

Comment: How are you reading the file? share your attempt.

Comment: I am trying to do a `var doc = XElement.Load(".\myxml.xml");` from my `index.aspx.cs` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Server.Path:

```
var doc = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/myxml.xml"));
```